# Reset index on multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

What I want to do is write a line of code that resets in the indices on some data frames. I thought I could write something like this

```
X_train, X_test_, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
map(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True),
                 [X_train, X_test_, y_train, y_test])
```

But it doesn't have the desired result. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a lazy operation. It doesn't run until you iterate over the map. You can achieve your desired result by simply running a list comprehension:

```py
X_train, X_test_, y_train, y_test = [
    df.reset_index(drop=True)
    for df in train_test_split(X,y)
]
```